# Uploaded Image doesn't get stored in the 'uploads' folder using php code

Tags: php

I used the code from w3schools http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

However, when I click Upload my whole form gets submitted to the database, but the image doesn't get stored in the folder in my localhost.

php.ini file

```
 <? php
     phpinfo();
     file_uploads = on;
 ?>
```

upload.php file

```
  <?php
      $target_dir = "content/uploads/images";
      $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
      $uploadOk = 1;
      $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
      $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
     } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
     }
  }
   // Check if file already exists
     if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
   }
  // Check file size
     if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
         echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
         $uploadOk = 0;
   }
  // Allow certain file formats
     if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
     && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
      echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
      $uploadOk = 0;
    }
  // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
      if ($uploadOk == 0) {
      echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
  // if everything is ok, try to upload file
      } else {
     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
       echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
       echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
  }  
?>
```

Am I referring incorrectly to the destination folder or is there an error in the code?

Comment: Did you include the enctype in your form, along with a POST method? Also make sure that all folders have write permissions. You're also using a conditional statement `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))` so make sure it's named.

Comment: yes my form has POST method and enctype

Comment: You're missing a `/` in `$target_dir = "content/uploads/images";` so do `$target_dir = "content/uploads/images/";` - Seems to be the most likely case at this point. The trailing slash is important.

Comment: @ Fred-ii- I fixed that error, but my image still doesn't get stored in that destination

Comment: Check to see what your max upload size is in your server's settings. It defaults at 2 or 4mb. Show us your HTML form also.

Comment: also when the code and settings are correct, it could be due to permission on the folder

Comment: make sure you have create rights to the folder

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with uploading files into the /uploads/requiredfolder.
Instead it was uploading files to `/uploads` and changing file names to requiredfolder & files names.

What I did was:

```
$slash="/";
$target_file1 = $target_dir .$slash . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload1"]["name"]);
```

Hope it helps somebody